# Blender 3.2 - Point Instance Node. Is this available or did the name change?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Blender 3.2 - "Point Instance" Node. Is this available or did the name change?

Comment: It’s called now instance on points

Comment: thanks you, how to mark as solved?

Answer (score 1):

With *Blender 3.0*, the [Point Instance](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/modeling/geometry_nodes/point/point_instance.html) node has been replaced by the [Instance on Points](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/modeling/geometry_nodes/instances/instance_on_points.html) node.

[image: Instance on Points]

The following options have been added:

- Via *Selection* it can be selected at which points an instantiation should take place.
- Not only single objects can be instantiated, but also whole collections.
- With *Pick Instance* and *Instance Index* it can be influenced which objects from the collection are to be instantiated.
- Furthermore, there is the possibility to apply a rotation and a scaling directly during the instantiation.